# Ftp not saving files on server

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest

I am having a strange issue with my ftp class its not sending the file to the server my main code is creating the file ok locally however its not saving it on the server no error is created just completes as if it has transfered it I checked permissions of the user and it is fine.

```
public void Send(string file)
{
    try
    {
        // read the contents of the file.
        byte[] contents = ReadFileContents(file);

        var requestUriString = string.Concat(_remoteHost, "/", Path.GetFileName(file));
        var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUriString);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_remoteUser, _remotePassword);

        using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(contents, 0, contents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
        }
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Helper.Log(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

And I checked the request uri is fine. After futher checking .net is reporitng

[image]

I have asked the web company to check there server cause it should be there for them even though I cannot see it in filezilla some reason?

This is how my uri looks like

> ftp://ftp.mydomain.biz/2018-05-09-14-11.csv

**Edit2** 
The file should go to the root.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in your `catch` block to see if any exception is thrown (or checked the "log" for any exception messages)?

Comment: Also check the size of `contents.Length` during debugging, or log it to see the value.

Comment: Yes I have checked both the file sizes are fine its quite strange no exception is created

Comment: Try adding this line, after you create your request: `request.UsePassive = false;`

Comment: @Icemanind same result is there a better exception catch I should be doing or should exception return a fail there

Comment: File is probably going into a different folder than you are looking.

Comment: its not on the server I have checked strange that I am geting an issue here

Comment: I cant post the requestUriString  would comprises me the security @mjwills but the content length mathces

Comment: @jdweng please see above edit i think u are right

Comment: @mjwills Please see edit 2 I have shown my uri thanks.

Comment: @mjwills  its ment to go to the directory worldfu but that is maped as its the only directory I am allowed in on filezilla.

Comment: @jdweng ny idea its ment to be going to the worldfu directory so it is

Comment: Use '%2F'.  See : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/91e2bed0-9e5e-4503-9e66-d224086e43a8/change-directory-with-ftpwebrequest?forum=ncl

Comment: I've had FTP issues before. Can be firewall issues in Windows and your router. Check you can save files using another FTP application - plenty on the web. Also use a port sniffer and check that port 21 is actually open. Also use Fiddler to sniff the network whilst running the application.

Comment: @jdweng what you mean why would .net send back sucesfull send then if that was the case ?.

Comment: I didn't say it fails.  Just put results into different folder.  I just gave the enhancement to put into a different folder.